# Activating mousedown on dynamically created object

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project where I want to "drag" data from a listview to a panel. The goal is that people can select the information on the listview and then position a panel with that information on it on a sort of flowchart on another panel.

Pretty much all of the code is already working but there's one thing which I'm still struggeling with. When I perform a Mouse Down on the listview, a panel is being generated with a few labels on it to be able to drag. The code below is a simplified version for readability.

```
private void createPlayerPanel()
        {
            var coordinates = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);


            // CREATE THE PANEL
            Panel panPlayer = new Panel();

            // SETUP THE PANEL
            panPlayer.Name = "panPlayer1";
            panPlayer.Width = 200;
            panPlayer.Height = 50;
            panPlayer.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            panPlayer.Click += new EventHandler(this.panClick);
            panPlayer.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panMouseDown);

            // ADD THE PANEL TO THE FORM
            this.Controls.Add(panPlayer);

            // BRING THE PANEL TO THE FRONT OF THE FORM
            panPlayer.BringToFront();
            panPlayer.Location = new Point(coordinates.X - 14, coordinates.Y - 12);
}

        public bool Dragging = false;
        Point location;

        Panel panSelected;
        private void panMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            panSelected = (Panel)sender;

            Dragging = true;

            location = e.Location;
        }
```

However with the same Mouse Down I would like to drag the panel to the flowchart. So in one smooth movement, click on the information in the listview and drag it to the second panel.

When I generate the panel, I also include a Mouse Down mouseeventhandler but which is not active yet when I perform the mousedown. So when I release the mouse and then hold down the mouse again, it works fine and I can drag the panel to it's new position. But I would like to do it in one action. So MOUSE DOWN > GENERATE PANEL > ACTIVATE MOUSE EVENT > DRAG PANEL

Is there a way I can activate the mousedown-event of the panel when I've finished creating it?

Comment: Try to declare the event handler in your PageLoad. The page causes its postback and your event handler for panPlayer is actually not declared

Comment: I can't declare the event handler in my pageload because the panel is being generated dynamically... The function of the eventhandler already exists ofcourse and is working fine. I just would like to know if it's possible when I'm performing a mousedown which generates a panPlayer if I can apply that same mouse-down event (which I'm still on) also on the newly created panel.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to.. Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8114/Dynamically-Created-Controls-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Right, I see your point Choz, however, this is a Winform, not ASP and there won't be any postback. I'm just looking for a way to raise a mouse-down event on a newly created control.

Comment: Aw my bad.. But it should be easier in winform imo. I will try test it once im done with my work. Haven't used visual studio for quite some time :(